# How to Add swipeable tabs in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I have a class which is a fragment made by using android hive code [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). Now, since each class here extends fragments, I want to implement [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) inside one class of the code. Suppose Home class is where I want to show tabs which will contain multiple option, say movies, games, etc. Is this somehow possible, it says to implement Actionbar.tab listener but that is not available.

Here is the code for Home fragment:

**HomeFragment.java**

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now i want to Implement tabs in this home fragment. Please answer. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i have use this Lib for this requirement

> https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip